# Docker MongoDB error : Can't call something

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have Dockerized MongoDB and trying to access it from another container running on the same host. But i am getting the following error on the container:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /1.2.3.4:27017/admin
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:227)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:160)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:183)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:144)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:195)
        at com.mmi.epg.utils.MongoDB.getDbVersion(MongoDB.java:117)
        at com.mmi.epg.utils.MongoDB.<init>(MongoDB.java:73)
        at com.mmi.epg.utils.MongoDB.getInstance(MongoDB.java:105)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:37)
        at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)
        at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:39)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:128)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:218)
        ... 13 more
```

Where fcdfd39baedb is the service container which access the mongoDB. I have this line in mongod.conf.

```
#bind_ip=127.0.0.1
```

Why did the service use an Internal IP address and had container ID before that to call MongoDB instance ? Am i doing something wrong here ?

Update: Please find my Dockerfile below

```
FROM tveuser/tve-repository:tve-centos
MAINTAINER karthik.jayaraman "karthik.jayaraman@xyz.com"

VOLUME ["/data/db"]

# Expose port #27017 from the container to the host
EXPOSE 27017

ADD /scripts/mongodb.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/

ADD /conf/mongod.conf /etc/

ADD supervisord.conf /etc/

RUN yum install -y mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server &&\
    mkdir -p /data/db

CMD supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

### Update

I have updated my question. I could telnet the IP and Port number from my service but unable to connect to MongoDB. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: That line looks like it is commented out.

Comment: Please show us the Dockerfile. You might also want to have a look at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mwmahlberg/m202docker/

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I have updated the question with my Dockerfile contents. I have also posted the complete stack trace. Any help appreciated.